# Run Gradle tests with multiple JRE versions/bits

Tags: java, gradle, junit5

I have a Java project built with Gradle with different codepaths depending on the JRE bitness. I'm writing JUnit 5 tests for the internals, but I need to run them on both 64-bit and 32-bit JREs.

Additionally, for future-proofing reasons, I'd like to be able to also test with different JRE versions. Currently the project is targeted for Java 17, but I'd also like to test with Java 21 (also 64- and 32-bits). This is somewhat optional currently, but a valued bonus.

Development is done on IntelliJ Idea (Windows), but it's not necessary that the tests run with all the above JREs from within IntelliJ. If they can, it would be another bonus.

I found a couple of related plugins but they don't seem to include JRE bitness selection.

*Note: The reason for the bitness differences is that different native binaries are used at runtime.*

Comment: This sounds like a problem that could be solved by running your tests in a container instead of complicating your build tooling.  You can create multiple containers with different JREs to run in.

Answer (score 1):

You should have everything you need using [JVM toolchains](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html) and [test suites](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html).

Here's a sample of how you can set up a test task which runs the tests in an Oracle JVM version 21, first in Kotlin DSL:

```
plugins {
    java
    `jvm-test-suite`
}

// other usual setup

testing {
    suites {
        val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) {
            useJUnitJupiter()
        }
        register<JvmTestSuite>("testWithOracleJava21") {
            sources {
                // Use the normal test source as the source to run the same tests
                //    Unfortunately the test suite plugin doesn't seem to offer
                //    a cleaner way to do this
                java.srcDir(sourceSets.test.get().java.sourceDirectories)
            }
            dependencies {
                implementation(project())
            }
            targets {
                all {
                    testTask {
                        javaLauncher = javaToolchains.launcherFor {
                            languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
                            vendor = JvmVendorSpec.ORACLE
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the same code in Groovy:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jvm-test-suite'
}

// other usual setup

testing {
    suites {
        test {
            useJUnitJupiter()
        }
        testWithOracleJava21(JvmTestSuite) {
            sources {
                // Use the normal test source as the source to run the same tests
                //    Unfortunately the test suite plugin doesn't seem to offer
                //    a cleaner way to do this
                java.srcDir(sourceSets.test.java.sourceDirectories)
            }
            dependencies {
                implementation project()
            }
            targets {
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        javaLauncher = javaToolchains.launcherFor {
                            languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
                            vendor = JvmVendorSpec.ORACLE
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle will search your machine for the installation matching the version and vendor you specify (and there are also features for it to download it itself and configure repositories from which to do so).

The plugin doesn't allow you to specify the target architecture directly, but hopefully the vendor field allows you to point Gradle uniquely to the JVM you want to use for each test.

Comment: Looks promising! Could you, by any chance, give us a Groovy version of this?

Comment: Now a choice of Groovy or Kotlin!